# Bluetooth Remote Controll for Voice input on Nexus 5

Tags: bluetooth, voice-recognition

I am using my Nexus 5 for 1.5 months now. Previously I used an iPhone 5. On the iPhone there was Siri and - when connected via Bluetooth to my car stereo - I could push a button on my Steering Wheel and start voice interaction with siri.

When I push the same button in Android 4.4.2 on my Nexus 5, it says "initialisieren", I think the english locale would be "initializing" and nothing happens.

It would be great to get at least some starting of calls working like "call my mom" or "call john doe" better would be also a working tts/stt (reading/dictation) of sms. Best would be if I also could change playlists (Play List Salsa/Play List Rock) or starting of the navigation (Navigate to Home)

is there any way to get those things working?

[image: The Initializing Screen]
<sup>Screenshot (click image for original size)</sup>

Comment: I'm not sure about the "Steering Wheel" controls, but you might wish to take a look at [tasker](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/tasker/info) (being German, just follow the link to AndroidPIT from there :) and the *AutoVoice* plugin.

Comment: so out of the box there is no way to use that standard voice recognition?

Comment: I can't tell, as I've not much played with that. Let's see if someone else has fresh ideas.

Comment: I have tried tasker now. It is a really powerful thing. But I have the problem, that my phone speaks the variables instead of speaking its contents:
[AutoVoice and Tasker: Speak recognized Variable says “percent varname”](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/62224/autovoice-and-tasker-speak-recognized-variable-says-percent-varname)

Comment: You might wish to see the above linked [tasker tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/tasker/info) and follow up the link to my ressource collection. Though that post being German, it links to several English tutorials, including those around *AutoVoice*; I roughly remember there was at least one with using Variables to be spoken out.

Comment: Solved that specific problem. Tomorrow I try to get it working with the button on my car stereo system. But it's kinda hard to programm all that features with that little keyboard and screen. Usually I use 3 big screens for programming and a mechanical keyboard ^^

Comment: Glad for the solution (and thanks for answering your own question and sharing it, just upvoted ;) And yes, the question has been asked for years to have a desktop version of *Tasker* to write profiles and export them. Trouble is, that would need all the environment (addons, configurations) as well. One might be able doing that in an emulator... Good luck further, looking forward to your solution!

Comment: The trick with the autovoice for car mode didn't work. Now I can toggle the task, but cannot get it to work with the car microphone as it does during calls.

Comment: Have you tried contacting its author? He's very responsive, and *AutoVoice* are his "crown jewels". Tell him Izzy sent you with best regards :) If there's any solution, I'm pretty sure João will find it. // Oh, if he did it, please don't forget to let us know the solution :)

Comment: @Izzy I don't have an answer from the author of the software yet but I have another solution for the initial problem (See answer)

Comment: @Izzy how did you resize the image or have you done it offline?

Comment: Just click the [edit] link and see for yourself: imgur ships a smaller variant when you add a `m` to the basename (e.g. if `abcde.jpg` is the large image, `abcdem.jpg` gives a Medium sized (which I used), and `abcdes.jpg` would give a (too) small one). Then I made the medium variant a link to the large one, using the normal markup elements for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to the initial problem. It seems that this is a common bug and in the software since at least Anroid 4.2. There is an Application in the Play Store that does nothing but reacting to the Bluetooth button and starting the voice recognition:

[Voice Command](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.itdevcrowd.voicecommand)

When I push the Button, I have to select what app to start, I chose "Voice Command" after that I am asked again and chose "Google Now" and then it starts directly in the Voice Recognition mode.

I don't know yet if it gets the commands over bluetooth or over the built in mic but it stops the music and starts the recognition.

This works at least with My phone (Nexus 5, 32GB Android 4.4.2 All settings to german and my Car Radio (JVC...))