# AutoVoice and Tasker: Speak recognized Variable says "percent varname"

Tags: tasker, voice-recognition

I am trying to automate my phone and later also my home with tasker. Therefor I need to define all those little Voice Actions.

My actual Workflow:

- Task Voice Recognition:
- Speak "What do you want to do"
- Voice Recognition
- Profile Recognize Start Call 1:
- Match to Regex: " (?<%callername>.+) anrufen" (Later also "ruf ... an" and "ruf ... auf ... an" and "... auf ... anrufen")
- Start Task "Voice: Call"
- Speak "Calling %callername" (%callername was selected in the Variables dropdown)

That workflow speaks "percent callername", so it speaks the name of the variable. But it should speak the content of the variable.

Later I want to look in the contacts for that name and get the corresponding telephonenumber to start dialing. Or is there any finished Calling Voice Action for Tasker out there I can have a look at?

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer/ got it working now: I needed to create the Task direcly from the Create Profile screen after defining the Profile. Assigning an already existing task didnt work, whyever.